# A question about tight sequence of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I want to prove the following: If $\{X_n\}$ is a tight sequence of random variables defined on a common probability space. Then given any subsequence of $\{X_n\}$, we can find a further subsequence (let us call this $\{X_{n_k}\}$) such that $\limsup_\limits{k \rightarrow \infty}X_{n_k} < \infty$ almost surely.

I can see why we need to go to a subsequence of a subsequence to get such a result. This is because if I take a modification of the type writer sequence $\{Y_n\}$ (as shown below), we will have convergence in probability and hence in distribution to zero, but we will have $\limsup_\limits{k \rightarrow \infty}$ of the sequence is infinite almost surely.

Modified Type Writer sequence:

$Y_1 = 1_{[0,1]}$

$Y_2 = 2*1_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}$

$Y_3 = 2*1_{[\frac{1}{2},1]}$

$Y_4 = 3*1_{[0,\frac{1}{4}]}$

$Y_5 = 3*1_{[\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}]}$

and so on...
Thanks!

Comment: Hint: the contrapositive of this statement is (essentially) "if $P(X_n\to\infty)>0$, then $\{X_n\}$ is not tight". Is this something you can prove?

Comment: Thanks. I can prove the statement within quotes, but what is unclear to me is that this is the contrapositive as there are subsequences involved.